# is it must to use parameters in setter methods

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method to set the length of a rack.

I am not sure if I have to put a length variable as a parameter in the method

```
public class Rack {
    int racklength;


    public Rack(int racklength){
        racklength=racklength;
    }
    public int setRackLength(){
        return racklength;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do.  When you set something, you need to pass in the external value you want to set the internal value to.  Otherwise, how could you set it?   So your code should be something like:

```
public Rack(int racklength) {
    this.racklength = racklength;
}

public void setRackLength(int racklength) {
    this.racklength = racklength;
}
```

When the parameter has the same name as the member variable, you need to use the `this` qualifier to tell the compiler which is the member variable and which is the parameter.  Alternatively, you could have the parameter named something else:

```
public void setRackLength(int length) {
    racklength = length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When an argument and class variable share the same name you can user "this." to refer to the class variable.  Also, change the name of setRackLength to getRackLength

```
public Rack(int racklength){
   this.racklength = racklength; 
}
public int getRackLength() { return rackLength; }
public void setRackLength(int rackLength) {
   this.racklength = racklength; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A setter method by definition should have a parameter to set the value to:

```
public void setProperty(PropertyType property) {
    this.property = property;
    // here this.property means the property that belongs to the instance, ie, 'this'
}
```

Having a "setter" with no parameters doesn't really make any sense.